# How to save data on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I take a tutorial to save date on Firebase in React Native.

When i compile it that show the error is `_firebase2.default.database.ref is not a function`

But the question that offcial tutorial is  `.ref` too.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Any one can teach me how to solve the issue , thanks in advance.

My rules setting on Firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Save data code in React Native:

```
export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {

    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    firebase.database.ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push({ name, phone, shift });

};
```

Comment: shouldnt it be firebase().database().ref('---whatever---')

Comment: @ParthGhiya , thanks for your answer that  firebase.database().ref('---whatever---')   is working , thank you so much.

Comment: i will post it as answer, you can accept & UpVote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong.

When u directly reference firebase, you should use it like this

```
firebase().database().ref('---whatever---')
```